# Delete a column from a delimited file in linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have a file in the following format:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
a|b|c|d
e|f||h
i|j|k|l
```

I would like to delete col3 (with the delimiter "|") from the header and the data as well.  Can this be done using awk/sed?

Plese NOTE that the data in col3 maybe empty (row 2).

The output should be:

```
col1|col2|col4
a|b|d
e|f|h
i|j|l
```

I tried:

```
awk -F"|" '{ OFS="|"; $3=""; print }' in.txt > out.txt
```

but the "|" is left out. I'd like the "|" following the header and the data gone.

Answer (score 22):

You could simply use `cut`.

```
cut -d'|' -f1-2,4- file
```

Comment: I need to get a tattoo that says, "Did you try cut?"

Comment: @Dean -- Wouldn't an incision somehow be more appropriate for that?

Comment: A little note, if you have a tab-deliminated file you can specify the tab by using -d $'\t' on the command line.

Comment: @plugwash The C-style string `$'...'` is a Bash extension, so it's not portable to POSIX. But yeah, if Bash-only is fine, you can use that. In general, you can get a literal tab at the command line with ctrl-v tab in many shells.

Comment: ... And of course, if you have tab-delimited data, you don't need to specify the delimiter explicitly at all, because tab is the default delimiter in `cut`.

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed or cut):

```
sed 's/[^|]*|//3' file
```

Alternative:

```
cut -f3 -d'|' --co file
```

N.B. `--co` is short for `--complement` and that cut also works when removing the last field.

Comment: This is the best solution. Just mention the column number to remove. In `cut` you have to mention all the columns that we want to keep in file. `sed` is efficient when you have 100 or 200 columns. You saved my time...

Comment: Perhaps point out that GNU `sed` is not necessarily the version of `sed` you have installed by default, though, even on some flavors of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{print $1,$2,$4}'   file
```

should give you the output.

it is the very basic awk usage.

**edit**

you didn't mention 70 columns... :(

try this:

```
awk  -F'|' '{s="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){f=(NF==i)?"":FS;if(i!=3)s=s $i f;}print s}' file
```

Comment: but my file has 70 cols.  Is there a better way than writing out all the columns except the one I need (which is say 45)

Comment: Thank you Kent and triplee.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible sed solution:

```
sed -i.bak filename -e 's;\(^.*|.*|\).*|\(.*\);\1\2;'
```

This will work great for your example, and could be adjusted for other examples, but isn't really a general purpose solution.

Explanation:

`-i.bak` Edit the file in place, first making a backup called `filename.bak`.

`\(^.*|.*|\)` From the start of the line, match everything up to and including the second delimiter. The parenthesis group this match (group 1).

`.*|` Match everything up to and including the last delimiter.

`\(.*\)` Match the rest and group (group 2).

`\1\2` Replace all of the previous matches with the text from group 1 and group 2.

Comment: I think that because of the greediness of the `.*` expression, the expression wont work when you have more than 4 fields. A more general solution would probably be: `sed -i.bak filename -e 's;^\([^|]*|[^|]*|\)[^|]*|\(.*\);\1\2;'`.

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho That's definitely a better way to do it.

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho Thanks!  But my real issue is that the file has 70 columns and I'd like to get rid of the 45th one.  Then, wouldn't it become hrad to use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut` is the right answer, but if you really want to use `awk` it's easier than Kent shows:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} {for (n=3; n < NF; ++n) $n = $(n+1); --NF; print}'
```

Just shuffle the fields after `$3` down, then by altering the value of `NF` you change the number of fields.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I've used cut.  For my need, that seemed to be the easiest and straight forward answer.

Comment: `--NF` is undefined behavior in POSIX so different awks will do different things with it.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution could be useful if you have many columns

```
awk -F'|'  '{$3="";$0=$0;$3=$3}1' FPAT='[^|]+' OFS='|' file
```

Comment: Don't set both FS and FPAT, set whichever one you want the script to use. If it's FPAT you'll need GNU awk.

Answer (score -1):

cut command will help to achieve this

```
 cat filname | cut -d'|' -f1,2,4
```

Comment: I do not find any problem in it and it works fine. Why is down voted?

Comment: The [Useless `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) is obviously a problem, and may have attracted downvotes. Also, with that factored out, this duplicates my existing answer from two years earlier.