# How to delete whole column from bash output containing table

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I would like to delete specific column from textual table I've got as an output in bash. Here is sample data:

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
15        20        40
10        30        50
...       ...       ...
5         10        20
```

Lets say I would like to delete whole second column to have something like this:

```
Column_1  Column_3
15        40
10        50
...       ...
5         20
```

I tried to use AWK to do this, by specifying that I want to print columns $1 and $3:

```
awk '{print $1 $3}'
```

but it doesn't work in general case when number of columns is just N.

**How to do this in bash?**

Comment: Dear Wojciech, welcome to Stack Overflow. While I mark your question as a duplicate, it does not imply that you asked a bad question. You question was very well written, concise, contained example data and example code of what you tried. Unfortunately, this is a very common question. Hence, the mark as duplicate.

Comment: Related: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222121/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361632/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716392/), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127670/), [this](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6872/exclude-a-column-with-awk), [this](http://tuxgraphics.org/~guido/scripts/awk-one-liner.html), ...

Comment: If columns are tab separated, maybe `cut -f1,3 foo.tsv`

Comment: @Shawn, easier as cut -f2 --complement foo.tsv, especially if there are a lot of columns.

Comment: @user2138595 I actually put that up first and changed it because afaik `--complement` isn't posix.

Answer (score 2):

Just clear out the column you don't want.

```
awk '{$2 = ""; print}'
```

Comment: probably pipe to `column -t` to keep tabular formatting.

Comment: @user3439894 There's no way to use `OFS` to make all the columns line up as well as `column -t` can do it.